# I have a simple Bootstrap navbar but cant align the navlinks

Tags: bootstrap-4

This was just a simple bootstrap 4 navbar but for some reason I cant explain why my nav-links wont line up.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-laravel">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/images/logo.png" width="80" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        <span class="ml-1">Risk management</span>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </a>

</nav>
```

[image: My Navbar]

Anyone got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  Here is the code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <img src="/images/logo.png" width="80" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    <span class="ml-1">Risk Management</span>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link ml-2" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```